# How do you create a photo that looks like it is being painted?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I came across a photo that looks like it is being painted. I like the look and would like to replicate it with one of my pictures, the question is how is this done or created? I am using Photoshop CS6.

Here is the image:

[image: Example Image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many settings you can play with to get the effect you want, so take the following as a starting point. Experiment and have fun.

- Start with a complete image, put it on its own layer and add a white background underneath.
- Mask off the area you want to become "blank canvas". Since you don't need a smooth, geometrically perfect area, use the Lasso tool.

[image: starting point]

- Select a bristle brush (new in CS5).

[image: bristle brush]

- Adjust the brush settings until you have a "dry brush" look. (I'm using CS6, which is why the UI looks darker than you're used to.)

[image: brush settings]

- Make white your foreground color and brush in the edges on the *mask* (not the canvas!) using short strokes. So as not to spoil the illusion, be sure you don't leave any hard edges from your original mask.

[image: painted mask]

The paintbrush image you'd add in after the fact. Eyedropper a color near where the brush tip sits, and use that to color the paint on the tip of the brush.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I am looking for. Quick question though, I do not have a tablet and having a bit of trouble replicating the brush strokes to look real. Any tips? Also which brush is that you used? (name)

Comment: create paths and stroke them with a brush this may give you a more realistic feel @Lynda

Comment: @Lynda it's Flat Bristle. Tricky to work without a tablet, but you can use the Fade parameter on the Opacity and turn on a texture, then use that brush to stroke along a path as skids89 suggests.

Comment: A tablet is on my wish list => Thanks for the information.

Comment: Easiest way to get real brush strokes: Buy a brush, paint and paper. Then scan it in and use it as a layer mask.